# Autowired component null pointer exception when calling method from another class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a class with an Autowired component and a method. If I directly call the method, it works fine. But if the call to the method is from another class, then I got a java.lang.NullPointerException error in the line where the Autowired component is used. The Autowired component is an interface component that acts as a proxy. I have tried different annotations for both the interface component and the autowired component, but still getting the error.

I don't get why the Autowired component is not null if the method is called directly but it's null if called from another class.

This is the interface component

```
@FeignClient(name = "authentication-server", url = "localhost:8010")
public interface AuthenticationProxy {

    @GetMapping("/headers")
    public HttpEntity<String> retrieveHeaders();

    @GetMapping("/auth-token")
    public AuthorizationTokenBean retrieveToken();
```

This is the class using the Autowired component

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProxy authenticationProxy;

    @PostMapping("/user/create")
    public UserResponseBean createUser(ValuesBean userValues) {

        UserCreateRequestBean bodyBean = new UserCreateRequestBean();
        ValuesBean valuesBean = new ValuesBean();

        bodyBean.setValues(userValues); 

        // This line triggers the null pointer error 
        // (only if method called from another class)
        String token = authenticationProxy
            .retrieveToken()
            .getAuthorizationToken();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", token);
        headers.add("Content-type", "application/json");
        headers.add("accept", "application/json");

        HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity =
                new HttpEntity<>(bodyBean, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().exchange(
                "https://api.acme.com/user/create",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity,
                String.class
        );

        String output = responseEntity.getBody();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(output,UserResponseBean.class);

    }
}
```

This is the class from where the method is called

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test/user/create")
    public void testUserCreate() {

        ValuesBean valuesBean = new ValuesBean();
        valuesBean.setDate_of_birth("1917-05-16");
        valuesBean.setFirst_name("Juan");
        valuesBean.setLast_name("Rulfo");
        valuesBean.setGender("Male");
        valuesBean.setOccupation("Escritor");

    UserController testUser = new USerController();
    testUSer.createUser(valuesBean);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add @EnableFeignClients to your application class?

Comment: Yes:  @EnableFeignClients("com.acme.apimiddleware.acmetoy")
public class UsersApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(UsersApplication.class, args);
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

First of all: there is no magic in this world.

Dependency injection is possible only due to dependency injection framework and Spring provides one of them.

When instancing a class using:

```
UserController testUser = new UserController();
```

You aren't using any dependecy injection framework only pure Java object instanciation.
So you can't expect @Autowired fields to be populated by magic.

The code below can populate @Autowired fields in a java object instance:

```
@Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

...

```
UserController bean = new UserController();
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean( bean );
```

But i think what you're aiming is using the UserController already instanciated by Spring instead of a new instance created by you. So the code below may be what you're realy after:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired private UserController testUser;

    @GetMapping("/test/user/create")
    public void testUserCreate() {

        ValuesBean valuesBean = new ValuesBean();
        valuesBean.setDate_of_birth("1917-05-16");
        valuesBean.setFirst_name("Juan");
        valuesBean.setLast_name("Rulfo");
        valuesBean.setGender("Male");
        valuesBean.setOccupation("Escritor");

        testUser.createUser(valuesBean);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mumrah81, you're right: I had to autowire the component I want to use, instead creating an instance manually

Answer (score 0):

Solved! 
The problem was that I was manually instantiating  the component called from the outer class, instead of autowiring it.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    UsersController usersController;

    @GetMapping("/test/user/create")
    public void testPolicyholderCreate() {

        ValuesBean valuesBean = new ValuesBean();
        valuesBean.setDate_of_birth("1917-05-16");
        valuesBean.setFirst_name("Juan");
        valuesBean.setLast_name("Rulfo");
        valuesBean.setGender("Male");
        valuesBean.setOccupation("Escritor");

    usersController.createUser(valuesBean);

    }
}
```